# YouTubeApi. C#. Есть ли какие то методы позволяющие получить artist name & song name?

Tags: c#, youtube-api

Делал небольшую программу (выводит список песен в плейлисте с характеристиками этих песен(song name, artist name, duration, thumbnail) и столкнулся с проблемой atrist name, я беру его как название ютуб канала - автора плейлиста (по другому оно не берётся, хоть на developers.google.com написано другое).
Т.к. song(item) title - это song(item) title, там нету разбиения на artist name. Можно парсить строку по разделителю " - ", но
во-первых, в некоторых странах слева название песни, с права имя исполнителя (и будет сложно определить где название, а где имя)
во-вторых, в музыкальных плейлистах группы в тайтлах обычно идёт только название песни (как раз для таких случаев я и беру имя канала).
Не знаете, как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Ютуб, это не музыкальный хостинг, там нет строгих правил как и что отображать в название, нету механизмов, которые позволили бы писать "Автор" и "Трек". Все, что вы можете получить через API - видно на странице любого видео. Вот вам [ответ от API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brHLo.png), можете глянуть что там нету разделения на автора и название композиции. Так что я не думаю, что данная задача возможна при использование именно API YouTube.

Comment: Тогда что можете посоветовать для решения?

Comment: А нечего. YouTube - это видео, значит и выводить надо это как видео, с тем названием, что есть. А если надо узнать информацию про автора и сам трек, то подключайте сторонние ресурсы, которые на этом специализируются.